# when to use distributed hash table instead of a "traditional" hash table?

Tags: hashtable, distributed, distributed-caching, distributed-system

Can anyone give me some intuitive examples? I have seen a bunch of notes but still could not get the "point" and advantage of "distributed hash table" compared to a simple traditional hash table. Thanks!

Comment: When the total data couln't be held in the memory of a single server (and you want to avoid disk IO)? When you need fault tolerance / tolerance to periodical resources unavailability?

Comment: Currently this question is too broad / unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of advantages that you can get over a traditional hashtable, when using a distributed cache:

- Distributed cache will be out of process. Data will remain cached even if user application restarts; traditional hashtable will be disposed with application restart
- Distributed cache can be shared among multiple applications, data cached by one application will be available to all others; traditional hashtable will be local to the process only
- Distributed cache provides scalability, i.e. adding more servers will add more memory (RAM) to be used for distributed-hashtable; where as local hashtable can only use local process's memory
- Distributed caching solutions provide extra features like replication for fault tolerance, expiration, eviction and dependencies etc which help user make better use of caching as compared to a hashtable
- Several solutions like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) also provide SQL-like queries to be used on in-memory data in distributed cache

You can look into Iqbal Khan's article on MSDN about [Distributed Caching On The Path To Scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx) for further understanding of need of distributed cache.